# Need help understanding this sentence: 「30前後とみられる男性が血まみれで死亡しているところが見つかり...」

Tags: translation

> 本日、午前11時頃、神奈川県横浜市のアパートで、**３０前後と見られる**男性が、血まみれで死亡している**ところが**見つかり、神奈川県警は、殺人事件として捜査しています。

I have no idea what 前後 could mean here. Is this about his age? From what I found, とみられる could be translated as "x is considered to be" so I guess in this case it would be that "a man (who is considered to be in his thirties) covered in blood has been found dead.

Does ところ here means "place"? I'm a bit confused since it's already clear that the crime scene was in an apartment, so why would they say that they found the crime scene again? I was also thinking that ところ could imply his state (covered in blood and dead).

Comment: One of the definitions of 前後: 数量・年齢・時間などを示す語に付いて、その数値に近い意を表す。ぐらい。内外。「十人前後」「三五歳前後」「九時前後」. So it translates to 'roughly', 'approximately' in your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“[前後]{ぜんご}” in this context means “approximately / around”.

It should be written as “30歳前後“ to make it clear that it refers to the age although we sometimes eliminate the part “歳(=age)” in informal conversations.

These two Kanjis have following meanings.
前=former, before, ... / 後= later, after, ...

Visually, it indicates something like this.
1, 2, 3, .... 30歳前(before thirties), 30, 30歳後(after thirtieth), ..., 41,  42, ....

“30歳前後と見られる男性” means “A man who is estimated to be around 30 years old”.

“~と見られる” can be translated as “estimated as~”. 
It indicates probabilities, and is used when you don’t have a clear evidence for your guess.

For example,
サルと見られる動物 = An animal which is probably a monkey.
(You don’t have any evidence, but you are just guessing that it’s a monkey).

As for “ところで“, it implies his state/condition in this context. 
“ところで” can be used to indicate states, conditions, circumstances, or situations in addition to its meaning as “place”.

For example,

> 1. 犬が走っているところを見た。= I saw (the situation that) the dog was running.
> 2. 彼が[苦]{くる}しんでるところを見た。= I saw the condition in which he was suffering.

The sentence as a whole is translated as...

> Today, at around 11 am, at an apartment in Yokohama city, a man was found in the condition of being covered with blood and dead. Yokohama city police department has looked into the incident as a murder.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Chocolate 最後と初めのthirtieth はタイポです、ご指摘ありがとうございます。2つめのthirtieth は after the thirtieth year、30代前- before thirtiesの意です。

Comment: @Chocolate うーん、日本語でいう"固い表現"にようなものの一つで、変わった言い方(口語であまりつかいません)として、She had been so beautiful until(before) her thirtieth year. というような表現があります。日本語に置き換えて考えるのは人によっては難しいかもしれませんね。